# Import specific columns from text-file into mysql with matching existing value

Tags: mysql

Trying to understand, is there any way to Import specific columns from text-file into mysql with matching existing value in the table.

Ex: I have a table, Ref_by and city does not have any values, wanted to load data from txt file. For values id 1 - Ref_by is 'Name1' and city 'Mumbai' & id  2 - Ref_by is 'Name2' and city 'Chennai'

```
drop table table1;

create table table1 (id int, name varchar(50),Ref_by varchar(50),Dept varchar(50), city varchar (100));
insert into table1 (id,name,Dept) values (1,'a','IT');
insert into table1 (id,name,Dept) values (2,'b','IT');

select * from table1;
```

[image]

If I load: it is going to as next rows, not sure how to match ID column from MYSQL to text files. Is it possible?

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'K:/Load/db/table1_columns.txt' INTO TABLE table1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' ENCLOSED BY ''  (Ref_by,city);
```

[image]

Needed result:

```
1 a name1 IT Mumbai 
2 b name2 IT Chennai
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by first loading data into a temp or data holding table:

e.g.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'K:/Load/db/table1_columns.txt' INTO TABLE hold_table1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' ENCLOSED BY ''  (Ref_by,city);
```

Then use join to match values from 'hold_table1' with target table 'table1' and either ADD or Update records accordingly per your condition

Comment: *Then use join to match values from 'hold_table1' with target table 'table1' and either ADD or Update records accordingly per your condition* Your code does not allow to set strict one-to-one rows matching in UPDATE.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it

Answer (score 2):

You must load your data in separate table, static or temporary, and update current table with another query.

In your case this can be:

```sql
-- create temptable for data loading
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ref_by VARCHAR(255),
    city VARCHAR(255)
    ) ENGINE = Memory;

-- load data from CSV to this table
LOAD DATA INFILE 'K:/Load/db/table1_columns.txt' 
INTO TABLE table1 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY `\r\n`
(Ref_by,city);

-- update working table
UPDATE table1 
JOIN tmp USING (id)
SET table1.ref_by = tmp.ref_by,
    table1.city = tmp.city;
```

`id` AI PK column in temptable provides imported rows enumeration which is used in UPDATE in rows matching criteria.

If `id` values in destination table `table1` contains holes then you'd enumerate the rows in this table and use this number in joining criteria.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it